# TCP sequence and ack values for TCP SYN and TCP RST

Tags: tcp

I'm sending a few **TCP SYN** packets to get **TCP RST**'s back. In order to identify each probe, I include a counter in the TCP sequence field. I noticed the following:

- when the sequence numbers in SYN probes are 0, 1, 2, 3..., RST messages have ack=1, 2, 3, 4..., that is **ack=syn_seq+1**:

> 12:17:27.181993 IP X.X.X.X.10104 > Y.Y.Y.10114: Flags [S], **seq 0**, win
>   8192, length 0 12:17:27.182008 IP Y.Y.Y.Y.10114 > X.X.X.X.10104: Flags
>   [R.], seq 0, **ack 1**, win 0, length 0 12:17:27.683148 IP X.X.X.X.10104 >
>   Y.Y.Y.Y.10114: Flags [S], **seq** 1, win 8192, length 0 12:17:27.683156 IP
>   Y.Y.Y.Y.10114 > X.X.X.X.10104: Flags [R.], seq 0, **ack 2**, win 0, length
>   0 12:17:28.184140 IP X.X.X.X.10104 > Y.Y.Y.Y.10114: Flags [S], **seq 2**,
>   win 8192, length 0 12:17:28.184147 IP Y.Y.Y.Y.10114 > X.X.X.X.10104:
>   Flags [R.], seq 0, **ack 3**, win 0, length 0 12:17:28.684993 IP
>   X.X.X.X.10104 > Y.Y.Y.Y.10114: Flags [S], **seq 3**, win 8192, length 0
>   12:17:28.685000 IP Y.Y.Y.Y.10114 > X.X.X.X.10104: Flags [R.], seq 0,
>   **ack 4**, win 0, length 0

- on the other hand, when my **probes start** with a **seq > 1**, the **first** rst will have **ack=syn_seq+1** as usual,
  but then the following rst's will have **ack=2,3,4**... regardless of the sequence value of the probes:

> 12:11:25.274636 IP X.X.X.X.59150 > Y.Y.Y.Y.59160: Flags [S], **seq
>   299**, win 8192, length 0 12:11:25.274649 IP Y.Y.Y.Y.59160 >
>   X.X.X.X.59150: Flags [R.], seq 0, **ack 300**, win 0, length 0
>   12:11:25.775218 IP X.X.X.X.59150 > Y.Y.Y.Y.59160: Flags [S], **seq
>   300**, win 8192, length 0 12:11:25.775226 IP Y.Y.Y.Y.59160 >
>   X.X.X.X.59150: Flags [R.], seq 0, **ack 2**, win 0, length 0
>   12:11:26.276324 IP X.X.X.X.59150 > Y.Y.Y.Y.59160: Flags [S], **seq
>   301**, win 8192, length 0 12:11:26.276332 IP Y.Y.Y.Y.59160 >
>   X.X.X.X.59150: Flags [R.], seq 0, **ack 3**, win 0, length 0
>   12:11:26.776940 IP X.X.X.X.59150 > Y.Y.Y.Y.59160: Flags [S], **seq
>   302**, win 8192, length 0 12:11:26.776948 IP Y.Y.Y.Y.59160 >
>   X.X.X.X.59150: Flags [R.], seq 0, **ack 4**, win 0, length 0

Is this the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, there was actually no real problem. When I inspected the packets with Wireshark and looked at the real bits in the packet, the ack value of each RST packet was set to `seq_of_syn + 1`, as usual.

`tcpdump` was simply using a **relative ack number** in the output. That's all.

Answer (score 1):

Each side of a TCP session starts out with a (relative) sequence number of zero.

Likewise, the acknowledgement number is also zero, as there is not yet a complementary side of the conversation to acknowledge.

The server responds to the client with a sequence number of zero, as this is its first packet in this TCP session, and a relative acknowledgement number of 1.

The acknowledgement number is set to 1 to indicate the receipt of the client's SYN flag in packet.

Now to your case:

Sequence Numbers got a dual role:

> If the SYN flag is set (1), then this is the initial sequence number.
> The sequence number of the actual first data byte and the acknowledged
> number in the corresponding ACK are then this sequence number plus 1.
>
> If the SYN flag is clear (0), then this is the accumulated sequence
> number of the first data byte of this segment for the current session.

Blockquoted part copied from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol).

So, your SYN flag is probably 0.

If so, that is the default behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You didn't convince me about the SYN flag, though. You can see from the excerpt I copied and pasted from `tcpdump` that my probes were all SYN packets. For instance: 12:11:26.776940 IP X.X.X.X.59150 > Y.Y.Y.Y.59160: **Flags [S]**, seq 302, win 8192, length 0